# Get data from select2 plugin to ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have multiple select fields with multiple select, implemented with select2 latest plugin. I want to send selected data with ajax to the Laravel controller. 
how can I do this? In the preview section of the browser network tab shows "No properties".

I wrote these codes to a submit button to submit selected services from select2 field.

```
$('#submit-service').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var values = $('.service-select').select2().val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/process_services',
        data: values,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
    })
});
```

Laravel Controller,

```
class ServiceController extends Controller
 {
     public function storeServices(Request $request)
     {   
          $services = $request->all();
          return $services;
     }
 }
```

Route,

```
Route::post('/process_services', 'ServiceController@storeServices');
```

Comment: `Console` your values to check the values you select are there or not

Comment: @RobinSingh when i click confirm, this kind of data shows in console, `[]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
concat: ƒ concat()
constructor: ƒ Array()
copyWithin: ƒ copyWithin().........`

Comment: just use `var values = $('.service-select').val();` and check it using console.

Comment: You said that there are multiple `select2`, which value you are looking to send ? All of them have same classes?

Comment: No. i meant one select2 field with multiple select, that can select multiple values in select field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your ajax code.

```
$('#submit-service').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(".service-select").select2({
    ajax: {
        type:'POST',
        url: '/process_services',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
              values: params.term // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return {
               results: response
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
});
```

Get the entered values using params.term in data. The successful callback handle by `processResults` function where initialize results with the response.

Comment: @hashan Solved your problem?

Comment: No. thanks for your comment but your code for load select options dynamically. but i want to send selected data to database via Ajax. is there any other solution? thanks in advance.